# Using a string as a file name with std::fstream.

Tags: c++, text-files, file-handling

I have encountered questions on data files which tells us to write a function to do stuff. In every other question we deal with fixed file names such as "abc.txt" and hence the functions doesn't generalise. I wish to know if there was a method by which data files would use a string variable in the statement:

`fstream file("abc.txt",ios::in|ios::out);`

and turn it into:

```
char str[20]="Newfile.txt";
fstream file(str,ios::in|ios::out);
```

Is there a way to use a string as a file name with `std::fstream`? I tried using a string but no such file is being created, though the program's compilation doesn't show any error.

Comment: Did you happen to look at the [std::fstream reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream)?

Comment: 1) the term *string* is ambiguous, it's better to say *character array* or *std::string*, 2) it's rarely a good idea to use the same fstream for input and output, 3) you should find some good references for questions this basic-- if your course text doesn't cover them.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the compiler. This way works consistently:

```
void do_something(std::string const &filename) {

    std::fstream(filename.c_str());
    // ...
}
```

This way works with new (C++11) compilers, but not older ones:

```
void do_something(std::string const &filename) {

    std::fstream(filename);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok.. But is there any alternate way to it? which would work in older versions..? Something which might not even use a variable but instead generalise the fn() i make..?

Comment: @user2038517: The first one I showed is a function that lets you specify the name of the file to open, that should work with any C++ compiler unless it's *excruciatingly* ancient (i.e., predates `std::string` having been invented at all).

Comment: Jerry's first solution works in older versions, just like he says. You can't *generalize* the function without a variable - how would it know which file to open?

Comment: Err if you don't want a variable just hard code it? `std::fstream("hello.txt");`

Comment: @user1520427, It says in the question that the whole point is that it's generalized.

Comment: @chris I was referring to his first comment on this answer, when he asks about "not even [using] a variable"